# PHP  and SwiftMailer : Decorator Plugin 'stuck' on first entry. 

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm having a problem with the latest major release of SwiftMailer where the decorator plugin will only replace the placeholder in the message for the first email address in the list, and then use the same data on all following emails - regardless of email address.

For instance if...

```
$replacements[test@test.com] = array('{firstname}'=>'Jeff', '{age}'=>'32');
$replacements[example@example.com] = array('{firstname}'=>'Mary', '{age}'=>'86');
```

The first email might say... "Hi Jeff, you are 32".
And then the second email should say "Hi Mary, you are 86". But instead, the second email is identical to the first.
Any ideas? I appreciate any and all help on this... Thanks.

This is my php code

```
foreach ($result as $user) {
  $replacements[$user['Email']] = array(
    '{FirstName}'=>$user['FirstName'],
    '{LastName}'=>$user['LastName']
  );
}

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$decorator = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
$mailer->registerPlugin($decorator);


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Important notice for {FirstName}')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setBody(
    "Hello {FirstName}, we have reset your password to {LastName}\n" .
   "Please log in and change it at your earliest convenience."
  )
  ;
foreach ($result as $user) {
$message->setTo($user['Email']);
}

// Create a message
//$template = file_get_contents('../html/full_width.html');  
//->setBody($template, 'text/html', 'utf-8'); 
//->addPart('Dear {FirstName} {LastName},This is testing mail.', 'text/plain', 'utf-8');
  // Send the message



// Pass a variable name to the send() method
if (!$numSent=$mailer->send($message,$failures))
{
  echo "Failures:";
  print_r($failures);
}
else
printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
```

And this is the plugin code

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of SwiftMailer.
 * (c) 2004-2009 Chris Corbyn
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */


/**
 * Allows customization of Messages on-the-fly.
 * 
 * @package Swift
 * @subpackage Plugins
 * 
 * @author Chris Corbyn
 * @author Fabien Potencier
 */
class Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin
  implements Swift_Events_SendListener, Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements
{

  /** The replacement map */
  private $_replacements;

  /** The body as it was before replacements */
  private $_orginalBody;

  /** The original headers of the message, before replacements */
  private $_originalHeaders = array();

  /** Bodies of children before they are replaced */
  private $_originalChildBodies = array();

  /** The Message that was last replaced */
  private $_lastMessage;

  /**
   * Create a new DecoratorPlugin with $replacements.
   * 
   * The $replacements can either be an associative array, or an implementation
   * of {@link Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements}.
   * 
   * When using an array, it should be of the form:
   * <code>
   * $replacements = array(
   *  "address1@domain.tld" => array("{a}" => "b", "{c}" => "d"),
   *  "address2@domain.tld" => array("{a}" => "x", "{c}" => "y")
   * )
   * </code>
   * 
   * When using an instance of {@link Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements},
   * the object should return just the array of replacements for the address
   * given to {@link Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements::getReplacementsFor()}.
   * 
   * @param mixed $replacements
   */
  public function __construct($replacements)
  {
    if (!($replacements instanceof Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements))
    {
      $this->_replacements = (array) $replacements;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->_replacements = $replacements;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Invoked immediately before the Message is sent.
   * 
   * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
   */
  public function beforeSendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
  {
    $message = $evt->getMessage();
    $this->_restoreMessage($message);
    $to = array_keys($message->getTo());
    $address = array_shift($to);
    if ($replacements = $this->getReplacementsFor($address))
    {
      $body = $message->getBody();
      $search = array_keys($replacements);
      $replace = array_values($replacements);
      $bodyReplaced = str_replace(
        $search, $replace, $body
        );
      if ($body != $bodyReplaced)
      {
        $this->_originalBody = $body;
        $message->setBody($bodyReplaced);
      }

      foreach ($message->getHeaders()->getAll() as $header)
      {
        $body = $header->getFieldBodyModel();
        $count = 0;
        if (is_array($body))
        {
          $bodyReplaced = array();
          foreach ($body as $key => $value)
          {
            $count1 = 0;
            $count2 = 0;
            $key = is_string($key) ? str_replace($search, $replace, $key, $count1) : $key;
            $value = is_string($value) ? str_replace($search, $replace, $value, $count2) : $value;
            $bodyReplaced[$key] = $value;

            if (!$count && ($count1 || $count2))
            {
              $count = 1;
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          $bodyReplaced = str_replace($search, $replace, $body, $count);
        }

        if ($count)
        {
          $this->_originalHeaders[$header->getFieldName()] = $body;
          $header->setFieldBodyModel($bodyReplaced);
        }
      }

      $children = (array) $message->getChildren();
      foreach ($children as $child)
      {
        list($type, ) = sscanf($child->getContentType(), '%[^/]/%s');
        if ('text' == $type)
        {
          $body = $child->getBody();
          $bodyReplaced = str_replace(
            $search, $replace, $body
            );
          if ($body != $bodyReplaced)
          {
            $child->setBody($bodyReplaced);
            $this->_originalChildBodies[$child->getId()] = $body;
          }
        }
      }
      $this->_lastMessage = $message;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Find a map of replacements for the address.
   * 
   * If this plugin was provided with a delegate instance of
   * {@link Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements} then the call will be
   * delegated to it.  Otherwise, it will attempt to find the replacements
   * from the array provided in the constructor.
   * 
   * If no replacements can be found, an empty value (NULL) is returned.
   * 
   * @param string $address
   * 
   * @return array
   */
  public function getReplacementsFor($address)
  {
    if ($this->_replacements instanceof Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements)
    {
      return $this->_replacements->getReplacementsFor($address);
    }
    else
    {
      return isset($this->_replacements[$address])
        ? $this->_replacements[$address]
        : null
        ;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Invoked immediately after the Message is sent.
   * 
   * @param Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt
   */
  public function sendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt)
  {
    $this->_restoreMessage($evt->getMessage());
  }

  // -- Private methods

  /** Restore a changed message back to its original state */
  private function _restoreMessage(Swift_Mime_Message $message)
  {
    if ($this->_lastMessage === $message)
    {
      if (isset($this->_originalBody))
      {
        $message->setBody($this->_originalBody);
        $this->_originalBody = null;
      }
      if (!empty($this->_originalHeaders))
      {
        foreach ($message->getHeaders()->getAll() as $header)
        {
          $body = $header->getFieldBodyModel();
          if (array_key_exists($header->getFieldName(), $this->_originalHeaders))
          {
            $header->setFieldBodyModel($this->_originalHeaders[$header->getFieldName()]);
          }
        }
        $this->_originalHeaders = array();
      }
      if (!empty($this->_originalChildBodies))
      {
        $children = (array) $message->getChildren();
        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
          $id = $child->getId();
          if (array_key_exists($id, $this->_originalChildBodies))
          {
            $child->setBody($this->_originalChildBodies[$id]);
          }
        }
        $this->_originalChildBodies = array();
      }
      $this->_lastMessage = null;
    }
  }

}
```

another related plugin page

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of SwiftMailer.
 * (c) 2004-2009 Chris Corbyn
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

/**
 * Allows customization of Messages on-the-fly.
 * 
 * @package Swift
 * @subpackage Plugins
 * 
 * @author Chris Corbyn
 */
interface Swift_Plugins_Decorator_Replacements
{

  /**
   * Return the array of replacements for $address.
   * 
   * This method is invoked once for every single recipient of a message.
   * 
   * If no replacements can be found, an empty value (NULL) should be returned
   * and no replacements will then be made on the message.
   * 
   * @param string $address
   * 
   * @return array
   */
  public function getReplacementsFor($address);

}
```

> Reference:
>   1. swift mailer plugin page: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html   (Using the Decorator Plugin)
>
> 1. Disscuss on official forum 1. https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/101
> 2. Disscuss on official forum 2. https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/161

Comment: It should be something like public function beforeSendPerformed() is only called once . How can i fix it? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't the send() method be called as part of the loop? Otherwise you are just iterating through all the users, and the send() will only be called on the last element of the user array.

```
foreach ($result as $user) {

    $message->setTo($user['Email']);

    // Pass a variable name to the send() method
    if (!$numSent=$mailer->send($message,$failures)) { 
        echo "Failures:";
        print_r($failures);
    }
}
```

Seems odd that calling code is responsible for calling the `beforeSendPerformed()` method, but if that's the case, I would add it before the `send()` within the foreach loop.

-- Update --

Try this:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Important notice for {FirstName}')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'));

foreach ($result as $user) {

    $message->setTo($user['Email']);

    $message->setBody(setBody(sprintf("Hello %s, we have reset your password to %s\n" . "Please log in and change it at your earliest convenience.", $user['FirstName'], $user['LastName']);

    if (!$numSent=$mailer->send($message,$failures)) {
        $failures[] = $failures;
    }
}

if (isset($failures)) {
    var_dump($failures);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. That make sense. Unfortunately, the problem still occur. Actually with this plugin i can send out mail without looping it. Now i send the mail and the FirstName, LastName is still not custom one.  It should be some error in plugin.php

Comment: If you don't put send() within the loop, is the plugin expecting an array? Right now you are passing an element of the array.

Comment: I get your point , but it don't change as i expected. for a same content mail , it is
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

Comment: Did you try adding the `beforeSendPerformed()` before the `send()` call?

Comment: Would you mind providing  example such as how to call it? Thank you a lot

Comment: public function beforeSendPerformed(Swift_Events_SendEvent $evt), i don't know what is the $evt

Comment: i have added another page, but it makes no big difference since there is two line of codes.

Comment: Not sure what $evt is either, there was no mention of this in the docs? If you can't find it, I'll take a look and post back this afternoon.

Comment: i will append  what i have find in my post. I am not an experienced programmer and i really need help . Thanks for it.

Comment: In the reference #1 it said i can design my own algorithm instead of using replacements array, is it would help and do you get any idea to implement it? Thanks

Comment: The header is working now, but not the setbody , would you mind correct the close bucket for it? since i correct it by adding 2 more at the end of statement , it said can't call function

Comment: i don't know why it works, but it just work
i have add setbody to message , simply with decorater
  ->setBody('Hello , we have reset your password to .Please log in and change it at your earliest convenience.{FirstName}, {LastName}')

Comment: Interesting, so the decorator does work, just needed to go in the loop. Glad it works. Good luck.